# Convert multiple rows with unique identifier into one column

Tags: excel, powershell

I found a PS script online that returns licenses for users within Azure AD. 
However, for each user, it returns one line per license, for example:

```
Name   | Licenses  
User 1 | Lic1  
User 1 | Lic2  
User 2 | Lic1  
User 2 | Lic2  
User 2 | Lic3
```

And I would like it to export as below (or a quick way to do this in excel):

```
Name   | Licenses  
User 1 | Lic1, Lic2  
User 2 | Lic1, Lic2, Lic3
```

I understand there is the option to copy each user's licenses and paste them back using the 'transpose' option but I was hoping there could be a line to add to the script or an easy way to transpose all within Excel.

Comment: Need some `VBA` code to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
# simulate data from Azure AD
$Data = @"
Name|Licenses
User 1|Lic1
User 1|Lic2
User 2|Lic1
User 2|Lic2
User 2|Lic3
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'
```

So you want to group Lincenses by Name, then ***do*** exactly that

```
> $Data | Group Name

Count  Name    Group
-----  ----    -----
    2  User 1  {@{Name=User 1; Licenses =Lic1 }, @{Name=User 1; Licenses =Lic2 }}
    3  User 2  {@{Name=User 2; Licenses =Lic1 }, @{Name=User 2; Licenses =Lic2 }, @{Name=User 2; Licenses =Lic3}}
```

To join the Licenses with `,`, iterate the groups and emit a `[PSCustomObject]`

```
$Data | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name     = $_.Name
        Licenses = ($_.Group.Licenses) -join ', '
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Name   Licenses
----   --------
User 1 Lic1, Lic2
User 2 Lic1, Lic2, Lic3
```